# Model prediction returns warnings

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I'm trying to build a model that predicts the probability for an athlete to win a medal.
I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

Here is what I've already done

```
#Cleaning df
    #Replace NaN with mean or average
    
df['Height'].fillna(value=df['Height'].mean(), inplace=True)
df['Weight'].fillna(value=df['Weight'].mean(), inplace=True)

    #Changing type to integer
df.Height = df.Height.astype(int)
df.Weight = df.Weight.astype(int)

#Target variable
y= df["Medal"]

#If Male =0, if female = 1
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].apply(lambda x: 1 if str(x) != 'M' else 0)

#Predictive
feature_names = ["Age", "Sex", "Height", "Weight"]
X= df[feature_names]

#Regressor

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0)
cross_val_score(regressor, X, y, cv=10)
```

But when I run the code, it returns me an error

```
warnings.warn("Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test"
C:\Users\miss_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:610: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\miss_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 593, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\miss_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py", line 1247, in fit
    super().fit(
  File "C:\Users\miss_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py", line 156, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(X, y,
  File "C:\Users\miss_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 430, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, **check_X_params)
  File "C:\Users\miss_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\miss_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 663, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array,
  File "C:\Users\miss_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 103, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

And returns an array like this : `array[NaN, NaN, NaN...]`

My X looks like this

```
    Age Sex Height  Weight
0   24.0    1   180 80
1   23.0    1   170 60
2   24.0    1   175 70
3   34.0    1   175 70
4   21.0    1   185 82
... ... ... ... ...
271111  29.0    1   179 89
271112  27.0    1   176 59
271113  27.0    1   176 59
271114  30.0    1   185 96
271115  34.0    1   185 96
```

And my y :

```
0         0
1         0
2         0
3         1
4         0
         ..
271111    0
271112    0
271113    0
271114    0
271115    0
Name: Medal, Length: 271116, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Why are you converting Height and Weight to int?

Comment: Try to test your columns one by one: `feature_names = ["Age"]`, then `feature_names = ["Sex"]`, and so on until one raises exception.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it and it seems that the Age column rose exception; it worked with Sex, Height and weight... But if I want to give the proba to win a medal for an athlete I should now his  age ?

Comment: There is probably a missing value in the age column, you can run `np.where(df['Age'].isna())`

Comment: Thank you roman_ka, i've run the code and it returned me `(array([   147,    152,    153, ..., 270793, 270804, 270805], dtype=int64),)`, I don't really understood :/ Okay so when I  run `df['Age'].fillna(value=df['Weight'].mean(), inplace=True)`, there are no exceptions rised, but I don't think it won't biased the results ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fill missing values for "Height" and "Weight". You should apply the same operation for the feature "Age".

First locate your missing values in this column:

```
>>> df.loc[df['Age'].isna(), ['ID', 'Name', 'Age'])
```

If you have few missing values, you can fill with the mean:

```
>>> df['Age'].fillna(value=df['Age'].mean(), inplace=True)
```

But if you have many missing values, fill them with the global mean is probably not a good idea. "Age" can depends on "Country", "Sport", "Year" even the "Season" (winter or summer). In fact, this is the same for Height/Weight: the average height in VolleyBall is probably not the same in Archery...